# tensorflow concat tensors row wise

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have an `BasicLSTMCell` which is fed into a `static_rnn` that unfolds `sent_max_len = 2` times. The input is a batch of sentences of `batch_size = 2`. Each word has an `embed_size = 6`. The output looks like this:

```
       e1           e2           e3            e4          e5           e6
[[-0.01236094, -0.00423804, -0.01091367,  0.00286771, -0.00911439, -0.00964547]  s1.w1      
[-0.0316297 ,  0.00904978, -0.02972977, -0.00720989,  0.00432076,  0.00946513]] s2.w1
                                       t1

[[-0.03660333,  0.00613474, -0.03758694, -0.0070029 , -0.00036427, 0.00386676], s1.w2        
[-0.04840172,  0.01757939, -0.05444464, -0.01508901,  0.01216465, 0.01938537]] s2.w2
                                        t2
s1 = sentence 1
w1 = word 1
t1 = timestep 1
e1 = embedding 1
```

I want to concatenate the outputs. But the problem is when I do `tf.concat` along `axis=0`, it takes the output of t1 and concatenates with t2, like this:

```
[[-0.01236094 -0.00423804 -0.01091367  0.00286771 -0.00911439 -0.00964547]  s1.w1
 [-0.0316297   0.00904978 -0.02972977 -0.00720989  0.00432076  0.00946513]  s2.w1
 [-0.03660333  0.00613474 -0.03758694 -0.0070029  -0.00036427  0.00386676]  s1.w2
 [-0.04840172  0.01757939 -0.05444464 -0.01508901  0.01216465  0.01938537]  s2.w2
```

But I want to concatenate like this:

```
[[-0.01236094 -0.00423804 -0.01091367  0.00286771 -0.00911439 -0.00964547]  s1.w1
 [-0.03660333  0.00613474 -0.03758694 -0.0070029  -0.00036427  0.00386676]  s1.w2
 [-0.0316297   0.00904978 -0.02972977 -0.00720989  0.00432076  0.00946513]  s2.w1
 [-0.04840172  0.01757939 -0.05444464 -0.01508901  0.01216465  0.01938537]  s2.w2
```

Because this `concated_output` goes through other layers and my final `predicted_output` is compared with `actual_output` where, the `actual_output` looks like this:

```
[[s1.w1.actualOutput]
 [s1.w2.actualOutput]
 [s2.w1.actualOutput]
 [s2.w2.actualOutput]
]
```

Obviously I cannot concat along `axis=1`, as even though it will give the output in the right order, the word embeddings will be combined.

Comment: Don't think you need the `batch-file` tag on this question.

Comment: Can you first concat along axis=1 then perform a reshape so that the inner-most dimension size is 6?

Comment: @greeness, it works. Thank you. Another way I found was: 
`output_sent = tf.stack(output_sent, axis=1)`

`output_sent = tf.reshape(output_sent, [-1, sent_embed_size])`

Comment: That's great to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
output_sent = tf.stack(output_sent, axis=1) 
output_sent = tf.reshape(output_sent, [-1, sent_embed_size])
```

Another way as mentioned by [greeness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667256/greeness):

`concat` along `axis=1` then perform a `reshape` so that the inner-most dimension size is 6.

Answer (score 2):

I would use tf.gather_nd where you need to provide indices to gather items from the given tensor. For example:

```
data1 = tf.constant(
    [
        [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],
        [[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]

    ]
)
indices = tf.constant([
    [[0,0], [1,0]],
    [[0,1], [1,1]]
])
result = tf.gather_nd(data1, indices)
```

will give:

```
[[[1 1 1]
  [3 3 3]]

 [[2 2 2]
 [4 4 4]]]
```

and then you can use concat with axis=0 to transform the tensor to your desired format

Comment: thanks, but the problem is, scaling. I need to do this with` batch_size` like 200, `embed_size` like 600  etc. The values I gave above in the question are simple values for trail and error, because they don't take too much computation time.

Comment: in that case, you can programmatically create your indices tensor